# Include clickable link as part of message from Whatsapp API

Tags: android, ios, swift, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a message containing a clickable link to a user in WhatsApp from both an iOS (Swift) and Android (Java) app. I'm using the url scheme as follows:

`whatsapp://send?text=$MY_URL_ENCODED_MESSAGE`

The message content populates correctly but the links aren't being rendered as clickable links when the message is sent.

I've tried using markdown, HTML and removing the URL encoding and just sending a link - nothing seems to work.

I've read that WhatsApp may have some security feature that prevents clickable links when the recipients isn't in my contacts list but all the people I've sent the message to are.

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to separate the message content from the links.

Based on a data structure that looks like so:

```
data = {
  message = 'Search here'
  link = 'https://www.google.com'
}
```

Your solution will look something like this:

**iOS**

`url: "whatsapp://send?text=" + data.message.uri_encoded + data.link`

Open WhatsApp on the device using the following:

```
let url  = URL(string: data["url"] as! String)

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
  UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
  # user does not have WhatsApp installed
}
```

**Android**

```
url: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" + data.message.uri_encoded + data.link
packageName:  'com.whatsapp'
```

Open WhatsApp on the device using the following:

```
try {
  String packageName = obj.getJSONObject("data").getString("packageName");
  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

  context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
  // user does not have WhatsApp installed
}
```